# pyGTK how to redisplay a top level window (with child widgets) after window destroy signal is sent

Tags: pygtk

I have an application which displays a window containing widgets every minute.  If I destroy this window by closing it in the window manager (linux), the destroy signal is sent. Then the next minute rolls around, at which time `self.window.show_all()` is executed and the window pops up empty.

So I did some investigating.  I executed `print self.window.get_children()` just before the show_all command, which returned an empty list.  So I executed `self.vbox.reparent(self.window)` and I get this response:

```
calendar.py:237: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_reparent: assertion `widget->parent != NULL' failed
```

self.vbox.reparent(self.window)

These two responses seem to contradict one another.  On the one hand, the empty list returned by `print self.window.get_children()` seems to imply that the window does not have any children.  On the other, the output returned by `self.vbox.reparent(self.window)` seems to imply that self.vbox still has a parent, which would be self.window (as defined previously)

I've tried using a popup window: `self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_POPUP)` instead, but I would like to be able to close the window through the window manager, so that I don't have to add an additional button just to close (hide) the window.  The popup window doesn't seem to provide this functionality in my window manager (awesome).

So if you want to redisplay a top level window with its children after it is destroyed, how can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried making another copy of the window class and showing that one instead?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Thanks for your idea. It seems so obvious now, but I couldn't see the forest for the trees when I posted. If you care to provide this as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You are welcome! If it isn't too much to ask, could you upvote the answer too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making another copy of
the window class and showing that one
instead? Note: This will reset anything that was set in the window. i.e. if a person did something to make label1 say 'Hi!' instead of 'Hello!', it is going to be reset again to 'Hello!', since you are recreating the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `Gtk.Window.hide_on_delete` as the handler for the `delete-event` signal; then closing the window will hide it instead of destroying it.